How can I fix the epic game launcher note working on MacOs
I downloaded the epic launcher game to get started on Unreal Engine but the launcher doesn’t work.
I’m on Mac os Sequoia 15.1. Tried the trouble shooting I could find such as empty the cash, deleted an install again, etc...
The launcher open the “Check for update” window then it loads and closes, but nothing happen next, and it start over. If I try opening it with terminal it works, sometimes. How can I fix this issue? What is the issue? Please HEEEEEEELP :slight_smile:
